# Rails application needs to be split

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing rails application and have a requirement to make a version of it which will need a different views and also some core logic changes. The application will still be 80%+ the same. I was thinking that we will need to split this application out, perhaps into three applications; the core logic and the two variants based on it.

Any suggestions as to the best path? Was thinking of creating a gem for the backend and including that into the other applications.

Comment: It you don't need to keep them in sync after, you can just copy/fork it.

Comment: Yeah we would need them to share new code going forward so forking is not really an option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've gone through this once before in one of my projects. The requirements was to have a big common set of features, functionality and code base but yet being able to customize and add new features for specific clients.

We went into the direction of having a core rails engine that could be mounted to different clients applications and then we extend/customize it based on client needs.

I'd recommend that you have a look on How rails engines are working here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

I can assure you that this direction was hassle free, simple, organised, scalable (+70 different clients/repos with same core engine) and we do not regret doing it in that way.

Comment: From my own research this seems to be the best path for us also. Interesting to hear your experience.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how big the app is and what its purpose is. Much like you would an API, you can version your controllers and views by namespacing them in your routes and classes, and you can inherit from your V1 classes to make your V2 classes, overriding the only things that need changing. This would work especially well if you had need to go to either the old version or the new version, all within the same app. So instead of

#### /app/controllers/user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
  end
end
```

You'd have:

#### /app/controllers/v1/user_controller.rb

```
class V1::UserController < ApplicationController
  def show
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
  end
end
```

#### /app/controllers/v2/user_controller.rb

```
class V2::UserController < V1::UserController
  def create
    # show didn't change between versions, so don't override it
    # only change create here so that its specific to our v2 behavior
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the idea but I think the code base could end up having too many fork points if we went this path. We also have classes with logic and some of these would need to be versioned.